# Why does PHP have int and float data types?

Tags: php

I have realized that PHP can treat `string` variables as numbers (as long as `int` or `float` values are stored in the `string` variables), for example:

```
<?php
    // Declaring two int numbers and one float number as string variables
    $i = "10";
    $j = "3";
    $f = "5.2";
    
    // Adding an int number and a float number represented as string variables
    $result = $i + $f;
    echo $result . "<br />"; // will print "15.2"
    
    // Comparing two int numbers represented as string variables
    if ($i > $j)
    {
        echo "i is bigger than j"; // this statement will be executed
    }
    else
    {
        echo "i is not bigger than j";
    }
?>
```

My question is, why do we have `int` and `float` data types in PHP, why not just store `int` and `float` numbers in `string` variables like I did in the above code?

Comment: int and float data types are used in those operations, PHP simply provides 'silent' type coercion to convert the strings into int or float before performing the numeric operations.   Those types need to exist in the language otherwise type coercion would not be possible, and those numeric operations would not exist either.

Comment: @Ben Cottrell But why can we explicitly create `int` or `float` variables (for example: `$i = 10; $f = 2.4;`)? I mean in the Bash shell for example, I think an `int` variable is stored as a `string`, but you can't explicitly create an `int` variable I think.

Comment: @Ben It could directly work on strings. Might be a bit inefficient, but does it matter?

Comment: @user Type is strictly only the property of an object, not a variable in that language.

Comment: Bash only has strings, and it's a total nightmare. In principle, it's possible, but in practice, programming languages usually expose data types that map well onto the hardware. Storing numbers 1-digit-per-char is outstandingly inefficient, and you can't do arithmetic on number strings until you convert them to better representations first, anyway.

Comment: there are some languages that do store everything in strings. Turns out it's really annoying for various reasons. "10" comes "3" "alphabetically" so wouldn't you expect "10"<"3"? what about "10a" < "3b"?

Comment: @Deduplicator It's less about storage representation and more about the language recognising a fundamental difference in semantics between numbers and strings;   i.e. `"1"+"1"`  is `"2"` by making the distinction otherwise it becomes a concat (`"11"`) instead.     Of course it's possible to have languages that don't understand the distinction, but that just means programmers have to worry about it because they don't have the convenience of number abstractions available to them.    But following that line of reasoning can lead to "why have for/while/if when we can do everything with goto?".

Comment: @BenCottrell PHP disambiguates the by using `.` as the concatenation operator, and `+` as the addition operator. But there are lots of other good reasons for it to have separate types.

Answer (score 3):

Efficiency.  All computers can do integer math extremely efficiently, as in billions of operations per second, and *most* (these days) can do the same with floating point.

*String* math?  Not so much.

PHP is fairly fast, but I'm sure many would wish it faster.  Do we really want to slow it down more, for some definition of elegance?  To what real purpose?

Analogous questions might be: why do we need a 64-bit computer?  A 1-bit computer can do all the same things.  Or: why do we need the x86 architecture when a Turing machine has been proven to be able to do all the same things?